# Infinite loop during Rails model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion

**The Use Case**

If users haven't filled their box with products up to their credit limit (6 by default), a method is called on the box model which fills it for them.

**Code guide**

The number of credits in the box is given by `box_credits`, which loops through all products in the box and returns the total value of them. This seems to work.

The boolean method `box_filled?` checks if the `box_credits` method is equal to or greater than the number of credits available (the subscription credits).

The `fill_once` method should add products to the box until the box is filled (`box_filled?` returns `true`). This will happen when `box_credits` equals the number of credits available.

**The Code**

```
def fill_once
  unless self.box_filled?
    # Get a random product from the user's recommendations
    product = self.subscription.user.recommended_product_records[rand(self.subscription.user.recommended_product_records.length - 1)]
    # Make sure the product hasn't already been included in the box
    unless self.added_product_ids.include? product.id
      # If fresh, add the product to the box, size-dependently
      unless product.sample_price_credits.nil?
        product.add_to_box_credits(self.subscription, "sample")
      else
        unless product.full_price_credits.nil?
          product.add_to_box_credits(self.subscription, "full")
        end
      end
      self.save!
    end
    self.fill_once # Here's the recursion
  end
end
```

The `box_filled?` method looks like this:

```
def box_filled?
  subscription = self.subscription
  if self.box_credits >= subscription.credits
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

`box_credits` are determined by this method:

```
def box_credits
  count = 0
  unless self.added_product_hashes.nil?
    # Takes product hashes in the form {id, size, method}
    self.added_product_hashes.each do |product_hash|
      # Add credits to the count accordingly
      if product_hash["method"] == "credits"

        # Depending on the product size, add the corresponding amount of credits
        if product_hash["size"] == "sample"
          # Get the credit cost for a product sample
          cost = Product.find(product_hash["id"].to_i).sample_price_credits
          count += cost
        elsif product_hash["size"] == "full"
          # Get the credit cost for a full product
          cost = Product.find(product_hash["id"].to_i).full_price_credits
          count += cost
        else
          next
        end

      else
        next
      end
    end
  end

  return count
end
```

**The Problem**

`fill_once` runs forever: it seems to ignore the `unless self.box_filled?` conditional.

**Attempted solutions**

I tried removing the recursive call to `fill_once` from the `fill_once` method, and split it into an `until` loop (`until box_filled? ... fill_once ...`), but no joy.

**Update**

Multiple identical products are being added, too. I believe the issue is that the updated record isn't being operated on – only the original instance. E.g. `unless self.added_product_ids.include? product.id` checks against the original box instance, not the updated record, sees no products in the added_product_ids, and chucks in every product it finds.

**Solution**

OK, this is solved. As suspected, the updated record wasn't being passed into the iterator. Here's how I solved it:

```
# Add one random user recommended product to the box
def fill_once(box=self)
  unless box.box_filled?
    # Get a random product from the user's recommendations
    product = box.subscription.user.recommended_product_records[rand(box.subscription.user.recommended_product_records.length - 1)]
    # Make sure the product hasn't already been included in the box
    unless box.added_product_ids.include? product.id
      # If fresh, add the product to the box, size-dependently
      unless product.sample_price_credits.nil?
        box = product.add_to_box_credits(box.subscription, "sample")
      else
        unless product.full_price_credits.nil?
        box = product.add_to_box_credits(box.subscription, "full")
        end
      end
    end
    fill_once(box)
  end
end
```

Using Ruby's default arguments with a default of `self`, but the option to use the updated record instead, allows me to pass the record through the flow as many times as needed.

Comment: it looks like you could refactored this code little bit, also many comments like `# Add the cost to the count` is not good practice

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to illustrate my thinking! Any thoughts on the recursion issue?

Comment: your thoughts little bit unreadable, many unnecessary comments, `self` in place where you can just remove it, combination with `unless .. else .. end` the same with `unless something.nil?`, I'm not sure but hope that if you just refactor your example you will found solution without help)

Comment: @IS04 I had a hard time understanding your comment, so maybe you could refactor that, too? ;)

Comment: Is there a better way of writing `unless something.nil? ...`?

Comment: `unless something.nil?` could be replace to `if something.present?`

Comment: @SamJames how about `something.to_hash`? `nil` gets converted into `{}` with that and no iterations occur on `each`.

Comment: @thankyour maybe you just write what is wrong in my comment?

Comment: @D-side thanks for piping in – how could I apply that within a conditional?

Comment: @SamJames wipe that conditional: if that `something` is `nil`, `each` will be called on `{}` that will produce no iterations. Otherwise - it will just iterate over that hash, that's not `nil` (otherwise we'd have `{}`).
 It's just `something.to_hash.each do |...| ...`

Comment: Thanks @D-side. Are you specifically referring to `unless self.added_product_hashes.nil? self.added_product_hashes.each do |product_hash| ... `? (Refactored to `self.added_product_hashes.to_hash.each ...`)

Comment: @SamJames exactly. Also, the last 5 lines (most of the method!) in `box_filled?` mean essentially the same as `return self.box_credits >= subscription.credits`: and even `return` can be omitted as long as it's the last line (implicit return!)

Comment: Thanks. This is now solved (see above)

Answer (score 0):

`unless self.added_product_ids.include? product.id` means no duplicate product will be add to box. So if all products recommend is add to box but the total credits is less than box_credits , may cause infinite loop. I'm not sure, but it could be the reason.

You could add

```
puts "Box credits #{self.box_credits} vs. credits: #{self.subscription.credits} "
```

before

```
self.fill_once # Here's the recursion
```

to see if this happens.

Comment: That's the idea – good spot, let me try with a bigger list of products.

Comment: Either way, the code doesn't handle this and it's a problem. Maybe it should count the maximum possible amount and raise an exception if it's impossible to fill the box. Once per attempt. Maybe `fill_once` should be one step, and the loop itself extracted into its own method (that handles that sort of thing). Hey, people, we are reviewing code here :D There's [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: Agreed! I've handled it now. If we could try to look for an answer to the recursion issue, that'd be handy?

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solve the issue – products are constantly added to the box with zero regard for the constraints. Multiple identical products are being added, too. I believe the issue is that the updated record isn't being operated on – only the original one. E.g. `unless self.added_product_ids.include? product.id` checks against the original box instance, not the updated record.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

OK, this is solved. As suspected, the updated record wasn't being passed into the iterator. Here's how I solved it:

```
# Add one random user recommended product to the box
def fill_once(box=self)
  unless box.box_filled?
    # Get a random product from the user's recommendations
    product = box.subscription.user.recommended_product_records[rand(box.subscription.user.recommended_product_records.length - 1)]
    # Make sure the product hasn't already been included in the box
    unless box.added_product_ids.include? product.id
      # If fresh, add the product to the box, size-dependently
      unless product.sample_price_credits.nil?
        box = product.add_to_box_credits(box.subscription, "sample")
      else
        unless product.full_price_credits.nil?
        box = product.add_to_box_credits(box.subscription, "full")
        end
      end
    end
    fill_once(box)
  end
end
```

Using Ruby's default arguments with a default of `self`, but the option to use the updated record instead, allows me to pass the record through the flow as many times as needed.

Comment: I don't think it fixed all the problem, I flag your question of migrating to CodeReview, you may need other reviews suggestions.